# Using AJAX to filter all data in a column in ASC/DESC order

Tags: ajax

I'm using CodeIgniter to retrieve a count of data in my table with thier respective agent name. I'm doing this by using the following statement:

```
$sql = SELECT count(*) AS cnt
         FROM table 1 t LEFT JOIN user_table c ON t.agent_id = c.id 
         GROUP BY COALESCE(t.agent_id, 0), c.display_name 
         ORDER BY c.display_name IS NULL, c.display_name;
        $query = $this->db->query($sql);
        return $query;
```

And this has given me the following output giving the table data from A-Z in terms of the name:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/juKtQ.png)

Now I want to be able to filter this data in ASC and DESC order when I click on thier headings of the table. Here is the code I have for my table:

```
 <thead>
          <tr>
          <th><div onclick=//Some method>Agent</div></th>
          <th><div onclick=//Some method>Count</div></th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
<?php
         if(isset($agent_count) && count($agent_count) > 0)
           {
            foreach($agent_count as $row ){                             
          ?>
              <tr>
                    <td><?= $row->name ?></td>
                    <td><?= $row->cnt ?></td>
              </tr>
          <?php }  } ?>
```

So here to order the data, I'm assuming an AJAX call needs to be made to order the data in DESC if it already is ASC or to ASC if it is already DESC. Also if I click on the count heading to get that data in DESC order, then the Agent column should also sort accordingly to its respective data.

Comment: You can achieve the same using javascript. There is no need to do another ajax call. You can just get the data once from server and then using javascript to sort the table.

Comment: Could you show in code example how I can get the data to be sorted with javascript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve the same using javascript. There is no need to do another ajax call. You can just get the data once from the server and then using javascript to sort the table.

Source: [Sort a HTML table on header click](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_sort_table_desc)

```js
function sortTable(n) {
    var table, rows, switching, i, x, y, shouldSwitch, dir, switchcount = 0;
    table = document.getElementById("myTable");
    switching = true;
    //Set the sorting direction to ascending:
    dir = "asc";
    /*Make a loop that will continue until
    no switching has been done:*/
    while (switching) {
        //start by saying: no switching is done:
        switching = false;
        rows = table.rows;
        /*Loop through all table rows (except the
        first, which contains table headers):*/
        for (i = 1; i < (rows.length - 1); i++) {
            //start by saying there should be no switching:
            shouldSwitch = false;
            /*Get the two elements you want to compare,
            one from current row and one from the next:*/
            x = rows[i].getElementsByTagName("TD")[n];
            y = rows[i + 1].getElementsByTagName("TD")[n];
            /*check if the two rows should switch place,
            based on the direction, asc or desc:*/
            if (dir == "asc") {
                if (x.innerHTML.match(/^-?\d+$/) && y.innerHTML.match(/^-?\d+$/)) {
                    if (Number(x.innerHTML) > Number(y.innerHTML)) {
                        //if so, mark as a switch and break the loop:
                        shouldSwitch = true;
                        break;
                    }
                } else if (x.innerHTML.match(/^\d+\.\d+$/) && y.innerHTML.match(/^\d+\.\d+$/)) {
                    if (Number(x.innerHTML) > Number(y.innerHTML)) {
                        //if so, mark as a switch and break the loop:
                        shouldSwitch = true;
                        break;
                    }
                } else {
                    if (x.innerHTML.toLowerCase() > y.innerHTML.toLowerCase()) {
                        //if so, mark as a switch and break the loop:
                        shouldSwitch = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            } else if (dir == "desc") {
                if (x.innerHTML.match(/^-?\d+$/) && y.innerHTML.match(/^-?\d+$/)) {
                    if (Number(x.innerHTML) < Number(y.innerHTML)) {
                        //if so, mark as a switch and break the loop:
                        shouldSwitch = true;
                        break;
                    }
                } else if (x.innerHTML.match(/^\d+\.\d+$/) && y.innerHTML.match(/^\d+\.\d+$/)) {
                    if (Number(x.innerHTML) < Number(y.innerHTML)) {
                        //if so, mark as a switch and break the loop:
                        shouldSwitch = true;
                        break;
                    }
                } else {
                    if (x.innerHTML.toLowerCase() < y.innerHTML.toLowerCase()) {
                        //if so, mark as a switch and break the loop:
                        shouldSwitch = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        if (shouldSwitch) {
            /*If a switch has been marked, make the switch
            and mark that a switch has been done:*/
            rows[i].parentNode.insertBefore(rows[i + 1], rows[i]);
            switching = true;
            //Each time a switch is done, increase this count by 1:
            switchcount++;
        } else {
            /*If no switching has been done AND the direction is "asc",
            set the direction to "desc" and run the while loop again.*/
            if (switchcount == 0 && dir == "asc") {
                dir = "desc";
                switching = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```css
table {
      border-spacing: 0;
      width: 100%;
      border: 1px solid #ddd;
    }

    th {
      cursor: pointer;
    }

    th, td {
      text-align: left;
      padding: 16px;
    }

    tr:nth-child(even) {
      background-color: #f2f2f2
    }
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>Sort a HTML Table Alphabetically</title>

    </head>
    <body>

    <table id="myTable">
      <tr>
       <!--When a header is clicked, run the sortTable function, with a parameter, 0 for sorting by names, 1 for sorting by country:-->  
        <th onclick="sortTable(0)">Name</th>
        <th onclick="sortTable(1)">Country</th>
        <th onclick="sortTable(2)">Count</th>
        <th onclick="sortTable(3)">Rating</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Berglunds snabbkop</td>
        <td>Sweden</td>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>4.5</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>North/South</td>
        <td>UK</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>3</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
        <td>Germany</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2.8</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Koniglich Essen</td>
        <td>Germany</td>
        <td>78</td>
        <td>0.9</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
        <td>Italy</td>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>4.5</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Paris specialites</td>
        <td>France</td>
        <td>7</td>
        <td>1.3</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Island Trading</td>
        <td>UK</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>1.2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td>
        <td>Canada</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3.5</td>
      </tr>
    </table>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Okay this worked for my names column, but for my count column which shows numbers it is showing like 1 11 12 2 20 22 3...

Comment: If column contains number values, just convert to number before sorting

Comment: @H2O Try this. it is modified for both strings and numbers

Comment: @fatalcoder524 Okay so now it does the number part correctly but in my question I had asked I want to be able to click on both the headings to filter it. So I've tried `x.innerHTML.toLowerCase() > y.innerHTML.toLowerCase() || Number(x.innerHTML) > Number(y.innerHTML)` to get filter number and strings, But doing so I can't filter any now

Comment: can you run the snippet now? I did some changes. On click of table header, it sorts properly now.